# Angular dynamic max min causes weird user experience

Tags: angularjs

I have an datetime-local input field with max and min attributes.

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="model.date" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}">
```

These attributes are dynamically set depending on the date from another input field.

Lets say the input field is pre-filled with a date like so:

[image]

If a user tries to change the day from 02 to 03. He starts typing 0 and before he can type 3 the input field gets reseted and looks like so:

[image]

It only happens if I set the max/min dynamically. Anyone knows how to fix that?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bm6rrzh7/2/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish there might be a better way to do it.  I think the issue is triggered by updating the min/max on the input as it's being changed.  If you are actually trying to limit the min/max of one input date based on another one, you could set those limits in a different way.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. How would you do it?

Comment: In the ngchange of the input being changed you could update the min/max of the other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is some problem when you do declare date with Time.

```
$scope.max = new Date('2015-04-04T23:59');
$scope.min = new Date('2015-01-01T00:00');
```

Remove the Time from date will solve your problem.

```
$scope.max = new Date('2015-04-04');
$scope.min = new Date('2015-01-01');
```

Here is [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bm6rrzh7/8/)

Comment: Nice try. But the validation doesn't work anymore. It is invalid all the time. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: @Sven  what this line are doing         `$scope.max = new Date('2015-04-04' + Math.round(Math.random()*10));
        $scope.min = new Date('2015-01-01' + Math.round(Math.random()*10));` remove Math.round part from them and it started working. http://jsfiddle.net/bm6rrzh7/7/

Comment: It's there to simulate a changing min/max value.

Comment: @Sven was that helpful to you?